# jQuery height and width not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have an image that has it's width greater than the height and it is still outputting using the second if statement in the jQuery. I do believe it might have something to do with the PHP sector outputting multiple image files. So I changed the id selector to a class selector, but it doesn't want to budge. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? I have hit rock bottom on this problem.

```
<?php $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
      $selectedId = $_REQUEST['id'];      
      $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM userProfilePhotos p, userProfileAlbums a WHERE p.isAlbumCover = 'Yes' AND p.userid = a.userid AND a.userid = '{$selectedId}' AND a.albumId = p.albumId");
        foreach($query1->result() as $row1) {?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function heightOverWidth() {
        return '<div style="width: 102px; height: 136px; border-radius: 3pt; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #C1C1C1; padding: 10pt">'+
               '<img id="profileImg" alt="" height="130" src="<?=base_url().$row1->imgURI?>" width="100" />'+
               '</div><span class="link-font3"><?=$row1->albumName?></span> <span class="font1"> - <?=$row1->albumDesc?></span>';
    }
    var img = $(".profileImg");
    if (img.width() >= img.height()) {
        alert("1");
    } if (img.height() >= img.width()) {
        $("#albumList").append(heightOverWidth());
    }
    });
    </script>

<?php list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize(base_url() . $row1->imgURI); ?>
<div id="albumList" style="padding: 10pt">
<img class="profileImg" style="display: none" alt="" height="<?=$height?>" width="<?=$width?>" src="<?=base_url().$row1->imgURI?>" />
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: So, right now it's doing this: `alert("1");` instead of this: `$("#albumList").append(heightOverWidth());` Is that correct?

Comment: It's doing the opposite. It's appending but not alerting

Comment: Are you 100% sure `img.width() >= img.height()` is true?

Comment: Yes I have checked the width and height of the image. in windows it's reading 669 x 502.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the width() to attr('width') and same thing with height. This will read your width/height attributes instead of trying to get the actual width and height. Your solution does not work as an element with display:none doesn't have any visible dimensions.

Comment: Good catch. I missed `display: none`

Comment: So... like this: *if (img.attr('width') >= img.attr('height')) { alert("1"); } if (img.attr('height') >= img.attr('width')) { $("#albumList").append(heightOverWidth()); }*

Comment: I'm still getting the second if statement executing. But on the bright side I learned something new today :)

Comment: could it have something to do with the looping?